# TCMalloc: delete and delete[] operators patching on Win-64

Tags: heap-memory, win64, tcmalloc

TCMalloc is a great heap manager for multi-threaded use (in my case OpenMP).
It was quite easy to get everything with tcmalloc up and running for linux, windows, 32 bit, but right now I am completely stuck with win-64:

- I use dynamically linked x64 libtcmalloc-minimal built with VS2012
- Everything gets linked just fine, program starts fine, and { new, malloc, realloc, free } work just fine
- With a first call to delete, or delete [], the program crashes as the delete operator from std library (in dbgdel.cpp) gets called on the following line:

  _ASSERTE(_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse));
- I tried to use Release versions of everything (as the dbgdel.cpp operator is only used when _DEBUG is defined) with no luck

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to share the solution I found (the mistake of mine):

in one of the linked libraries in the project I forgot the "_DEBUG" preprocessor macro in the Release build. Removing it solved the problem.